# Intersection of $\{ [n\sqrt{2}]\mid n \in \mathbb{N}^* \}$ and $\{ [n(2+\sqrt{2})]\mid n \in \mathbb{N}^* \}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find the intersection of sets $A$ and $B$ where
$$A = \{ [n\sqrt{2}]\mid n \in \mathbb{N}^* \}$$
$$B = \{ [n(2+\sqrt{2})]\mid n \in \mathbb{N}^* \}.$$

([$x$] is the integer part of $x$)

Using the computer, we found common elements.

Does anyone have an idea to solve?

Comment: By the way, it is much more popular to use $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for the integer part of $x$ than $[x]$.  I'm not saying you're wrong, but you might want to use more mainstream notation if you want to communicate with people.  Notice that one commenter didn't know what $[x]$ meant.  Also, I have never seen $\mathbb{N}^*$ before.  Does it refer to the positive integers?  Again, I'd suggest using something more popular, like $\mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: This problem and its solution and be found in the classic book _Concrete Mathematics_ by Graham, Knuth, and Patshnik.  They prove Dicu's conjecture below is also true.  These days, just about any math book can be downloaded off the Internet, if you know where to look, but it's almost certainly illegal.

Comment: If you had worked out some of the numbers with a calculator you should have noticed that the intersection appears to be empty.

Comment: It's all here -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence

Comment: @Doc : I clicked on the link. The book _Concrete Mathematics_ contains an exercise whose conclusion implies "Rayleigh's Theorem", but does not mention Rayleigh's Theorem by name.

Comment: @MihaiDicu : What common elements did the computer find?  I don't think there should be any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as [*Beatty sequences*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) and they've been quite thoroughly studied (you can find one of your two sequences at http://oeis.org/A001951 ).  The most interesting property (and most relevant here) is that if $r$ and $s$ are irrational numbers with $r,s \gt 1$ and $\frac1r+\frac1s=1$, then the sequences $R=\left\{\lfloor (nr)\rfloor\right\}$ and $S=\left\{\lfloor (ns)\rfloor\right\}$ are complementary: $R\cap S=\emptyset$ and $R\cup S=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I noted in a comment that proving this property appears in the book _Concrete Mathematics_ as an exercise, but I don't think they use the terms "Beatty sequences" or "Rayleigh's Theorem".

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that exists $m,n\in\mathbb{N^*}$ such that $[n\sqrt{2}]=[(2+\sqrt{2})m]=t\in\mathbb{N^*}.$
Then $t<n\sqrt{2}<n+1,\quad t<(2+\sqrt{2})m<t+1\implies \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2}}<n<\dfrac{t+1}{\sqrt{2}},\quad \dfrac{t}{2+\sqrt{2}}<m<\dfrac{t+1}{2+\sqrt{2}}\stackrel{(+)}{\implies} t<n+m<t+1,\;\text{false}\implies A\cap B=\emptyset.$

Answer (score -2):

Their intersection is the empty set

Comment: It is surprising that it is possible $A \cup B=\mathbb{N^*}$

Comment: @Nahai, Nice "conjecture".  I actually like your problem more :)

Comment: Why two downvotes?  Sure, it gives away the answer, but if you experiment with a calculator, you'll find that the intersection is almost certainly empty.  This answer does not give a complete solution, unlike many that do not receive any downvotes.